# Switch from full time to part time due to illness

Tags: stress, part-time, australia

Over the past few months I've gotten quite ill, and because I've developed quite bad anxiety. I love my job, though I find working full time is exhausting, and I feel that going part time will help contribute to a healthier mind.

The company I work at is only small, and I feel like I'd be letting a lot of people down if dropped to part time, as I was hired as full time.

I was hoping for any advice or perspectives on the situation, as I'm not sure how I should approach my manager, and am worried on losing my job because of this.

Any help is appreciated!

(P.S I'm new here and not sure if I've tagged this question correctly, let me know if I should assign more suitable tags)

Comment: Where in the world are you? In some places, reducing to part-time is something your employer has to make possible by law, in other places they can fire you because they don't like the color of your shirt today.

Comment: Location tag please.

Comment: @MisterPositive My location is australia (I've just added that tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review your Company Manual first if the company allows employment status transfers like that.If it isn't stated in the manual, then consult an HR personnel.

Afterwards, if transfers like that are possible, then talk to your manager about your intent to transfer to part time.

Although putting myself on the shoes of the management, it's quite unlikely that I will let you transfer, since what I required in the first place is full time personnel dedicated on the project, not part time. If I wanted part time personnel I would have posted work offers of that nature in the first place.

EDIT: since you mention exhaustion as the reason, there are other ways management can try to help with your current condition, such as providing incentive leaves or weekend dinners to help relieve stress.

It's possible especially if the management values it's employees. Just remember that when you company does provide benefits as these, be grateful and show your appreciation by accomplishing projects and accomplishing them well.

Comment: Most importantly, if this is causing you anxiety, then you have medical reason to go to part-time, so get with a medical professional and have them write it up as something you medically need.

Comment: @HLGEM Thanks for the advice. I'll go talk to a professional about these issues, maybe I'd be able to sort them out without having to part time, or only going part time for a short period.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about letting your colleagues down. What if it was the other way round, if you were totally healthy, and a colleague wanted to reduce their hours because of bad health, would you feel let down, or would you want them to get well?

There is an old saying: If you don't ask, you don't get. It doesn't matter what your employee handbook says, ask for a reduction of hours. The question is whether the company values you or not, and in a very small company, whether the boss likes you or not. And if they are given the choice of having you for 20 or 25 hours, or not having you at all, or having you work fulltime and getting sick, what will they choose?

And I would assume that you might be a bit flexible with hours - that's the good thing about a part time employee that if there is a real need, and they are willing, then they can increase their hours much easier than a full time employee.